# Increment the value, when a new tuples is entered

Tags: web2py

As I have the following code, where in their is a table named **Bill**, in which I want to increment the value of the **Bill_ID** by 1 as and when I try to enter new values(or tuples) in the respective table.

```
# defination of Bill
db.define_table('Bill',
                Field('Bill_ID',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Billing_Date', requires=IS_DATETIME()),
                Field('Local_Customer_ID', db.Local_Customer, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Retail_Customer_ID', db.Retail_Customer, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Total_Price', 'double', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
```

I want to know that what I have to do, to get the result as i specified above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want `Bill_ID` to increment by 1 for each new record inserted, there is no real need for that field, as web2py already includes an `id` field that is an auto-incrementing integer field. If you really want the field name to be `Bill_ID` rather than `id`, then you can do so by defining the `Bill_ID` field as the `id` field for the table:

```
Field('Bill_ID', type='id')
```

Note, you should not attempt to explicitly set or change the value of the field in this case, as it will be handled automatically by the database on each insert.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to display 'Bill_ID' on the screen during insertion of data.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. Do you want the user to enter the Bill_ID value? If so, what is the point of forcing it to increment by 1? If you want to enforce incrementing by 1, you should not let the user enter a value. Or do you just want to display the value that will be entered? If so, keep in mind (a) it will not be possible to use the database's auto-increment feature, as the ID won't be known until after the insert, and (b) with alternative solutions, there will be no way to guarantee the number shown will be allowed (in case two users are simultaneously filling out the form).

Comment: OK. Thank you for your suggestion.